# How to test in-development Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, packaging

I'm developing an "indent" package in Python (for fun and practise).

I've structured the source tree like this:

```
.
├── src
│   └── indent
│       └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_indent.py
```

which I believe is correct and common practice for Python packages.

`test_indent.py` tries to import from `indent`, which I saw in [the pypa sample package](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/main/tests/test_simple.py#L7)

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main

from indent import Indent


class TestIndent(unittest.TestCase):
    def testDefaultsOneLevel(self):
        f = io.StringIO()
        with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):
            with Indent():
                print('hello')
        self.assertEqual(f.getvalue(), '    hello\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But no matter how I try to run the tests, `python tests/test_indent.py`, `python -m unittest discover tests`,
`python -m unittest discover .`, I always get the expected ModuleNotFoundError because of that import.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indent'
```

How can Python test suites be coded in the first place, incorporated into the package codebase, and executed?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. Did you take a look here? https://github.com/tomchen/example_pypi_package Their test suite is quite strange.

Comment: @C-3PO the import statements in its tests directory are of the same kind as in [the pypa sample project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/main/tests/test_simple.py#L7), they just `import packagename` directly, no relative imports. But your link has a good README, and it says it uses a package called `tox` for testing. Is that the standard method of testing packages?